# Identify Hawaiian coordinate system

Tags: coordinate-system

I've come across the following coordinates:

```
x = 600907.76
y = 2437133
```

It's a coordinate located in Hawaii. I thought it was UTM, but the negative x coordinate makes me think otherwise. Anyone know what it should be?

Comment: There are at least 5 State Plane coordinate systems for Hawaii and there's no reason to believe any of them are it. Where did you come across this? The actual source is always the best place to look, the evidence comes in many forms.

Comment: That x is not negative. It is utm.

Comment: Interesting change of the X coordinate... http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/176227/revisions

Comment: Sometimes in utm when you see a negative x they are using one zone adjacent to the right I think

Comment: Good to know. I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like utm.

This is Honolulu.

UTM Easting 618,431.58

UTM Northing    2,357,505.97

Yes it is indeed.

X is easting
Y is northing

Zone I think is 4N but check

Comment: thanks! the negative value threw me off as i am a novice to this stuf